# Java Packet Handler Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, netty

I have a quick general question. I am currently using Netty to handle TCP and UDP packets coming from a client. I have the socket listeners each on a separate thread and it works great.

My concern now is, when traffic starts hitting it heavily, I don't think a single thread for each handler to manage messages will suffice. Is it correct to generate a new thread per message (I feel like it's not)? Or should I use something like  a Threadpool for this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is some example code for the message handler. I wrote some pseudo code to visualize this process. It might help you guys too.

```
    @Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) {
    //This will likely need made into a thread
    //SocketDecoder.decode(packet.content().toString(CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
    //Handle decoded message, will return CharSequence
    DatagramPacket response = Namespace.Decoder.createDatagram(packet, "hello");
    ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an educated guess.

By that I mean to say that you should consider the following programming standpoints for server sided design.

1) What does this server do? Does it just relay messages or is there processing to be done? 
If there is processes that need to be done it is highly likely that handling incoming message will not be a concern as the processes may be the limiting factor.

2) How much "traffic" do you expect? What is the estimated server load at any time? 
I know this is hard when you build your first server. But you need to know you target. If you think the whole world will use it you really need to prepare for it. Otherwise I would suggest just trying to test yourself.

Now as you know many game servers/messaging servers are multi-servers they have one main server and they delegate work to others which all can communicate with each other if needed. Perhaps that is what you need depending on the type of program you are after.

But really you should try to create a server to test. I would suggest a single threaded message listener/packet handler. And if you need to process something shoot off another processing thread. 
Really server design principles like the only you ask only come into full force over thousands of users. And even then it heavily depends on the processes you need to run on the server.

Comment: This will be a game server but we are nowhere near the point where we are going to be communicating through to other servers.

With the delegation, is it basically just making service calls over a network and then executing a promise when it returns?

Comment: It also sounds like it would be a good idea to thread the processes as that creates the async process that the delegation will force us into, so it would be best to build with that in mind from the getgo, would it not?

Comment: The most common and easily example is login. For a game server there is a lot of processing so most games have a few dedicated login/authorization system. Another example of a server that is there just to provide commincation between servers can be inter-server friends lists... or world segmentation/travel screens some games each area is its own server... these are all high demand games though

Comment: Ok, this gave me an idea of the architecture involved so I know what to keep in mind as I build this. Thanks for the visualization.